# How to transform the data in elastic functionbeat?

Tags: kibana

Using the help of elastic functionBeat I'm logging the cloud-watch to kibana. This is the below example:

> "message":
>   "2019-10-23T14:39:45.360Z\tcef55d0c-eg77-4e7a-9578-155b2260f103\tINFO\tjhon { status: 'success', "reason": "payment is not done" }\n",

The **message** key is holding a plain text, I want to transform this key over the fly before it reached the kibana.